# Zf2 - Using sessions / logged in status across multiple web sites

Tags: api, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am using Zend Framework 2 with ApiGility.

I have the following scenario:

1. A website where users login and manage their accounts: www.website.com
2. Apps hosted separately: app.website.com (that users want to use)

The sub-domain is not necessarily hosted on the same environment or even in the same datacenter.

Now, if a user accesses an app directly, I need to check if they are logged into the main website so that I can grab user related information needed by the apps.

I am not 100% sure of the best way to go about this.

For the App to work I need the following:

1. A 32 bit code (a unique identifier that the app uses in place of private information)
2. Account balance (to make payments for app services)

To get the 32 Bit code, I was thinking of setting up the following:

```
    www.website.com/api/is/logged/in
```

Which would return the 32 bit code I need, if the user was logged in.

To get the account balance I would then use the code:

```
    www.website.com/api[:/code]/get/account/balance
```

If the user was not logged in then the app would provide a form for the user to login which would be sent to: www.website.com/api/logg/user/in

If the users account balance needed to be topped up, then I would likely open an iframe to a payment page on the www.website.com for the user to make a secure payment.

This is kind of new territory to me so not 100% sure of the direction I should be taking or best practices...

Any advice appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to implement Single Sign-On (SSO) between a number of completely distinct applications.  I would check out SimpleSAMLphp...it will do everything you need:

- https://simplesamlphp.org/
- https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for this. I have looked at this in some other posts but before I embark on that journey I need to make sure the same thing can not be done using Apigility alone.